# Can the resources of Titan be of any use for colonisation of the Saturn system

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, colonization, saturn, natural-resources, planetary-resources

Will the resources of Titan aid outer solar system exploration?
What does Titan have?
Well:
*Lakes of ethane and methane
*Thick atmosphere, mostly nitrogen
*Ices stored in the rocks (the rocks are ices, actually)
I am asking if and how these resources will affect the course of outer solar system exploration.

Comment: Colonization is so far in the future that questions regarding it are basically science fiction. The one exception - and I kind of hate even to say this - might be Mars.

Comment: @OrganicMarble not necessarily. believe it or not, we get closer to colonizing mars every day, every time a starship test goes well, every landing of a superheavy booster. Every screw placed in the models, every wrench in the works. So, yes, it may be fictional right now, but not for long. A wise person once said, "Today's science fiction is tomorrow's truth". Of course, I am not trying to be rude or anything, I'm just saying.

Comment: The existing answer probably needn't change either way, but the title question is different than the question posed in the last sentence.  Could you clarify which one you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know very little about the goals, scope and means of a hypothetical colonisation of the Saturn system.
Thus it is difficult to say anything meaningful about its edge over other locations in the same system.

That said...

The other moons of Saturn have:

- Rock
- Ice
- Low surface gravity

Titan has:

- Rock
- Ice
- **Extra stuff**, like lakes and an atmosphere
- Moderate surface gravity.

With nothing else to go from, it's reasonable to assume to that having access to **extra stuff** makes it stand out.

The surface gravity is an issue for current technology though. With rocket propulsion it is significantly more difficult to get something into orbit from Titan than from any other moon of Saturn. Emerging technology could make this go either way. A [nuclear aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear-powered_aircraft) would favour the atmosphere of Titan, while [space tethers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_tether) would favour small airless worlds. We don't know which of these (if any) would be more relevant in the future.

**Precedence**

The little use up to this point of the Saturn system has put priority on Titan, mostly because it is more *interesting*. Airless rocks are a dime on a dozen in the solar system, and Titan is not that.

Pioneer 11 and Voyager 1 had their flyby trajectories specifically chosen to get observations of Titan.

Cassini had a dedicated probe ([Huygens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini%E2%80%93Huygens#Huygens_probe)) to land on Titan.

The only non-exploratory use of any Saturn system object to date is probably the repeat flybys of Cassini of Titan ([ball or yarn](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/17393/the-ball-of-yarn-cassinis-orbits/)). This was not done *only* to get data on Titan, but also to alter the trajectory to reach other goals in the system. This took advantage of the is significant mass of the moon, the only practical use of anything in that system to date.

Comment: While it's harder to launch from Titan, it's *much* easier to land there. Also, the inner moons likely encounter substantial amounts of debris from the rings as well as radiation from Saturn's magnetosphere (though not nearly as bad as Jupiter's radiation environment). Titan is at the outer fringes of the magnetosphere, far from the rings and radiation belts, and its surface is very well shielded by its thick atmosphere.